# Jasper Reports Round Rectangle not Rendering Correctly

Tags: jasper-reports, rounded-corners

This is very strange to me.
Using: Java 8, Spring Boot, Jasper 6.4.0

I created a clean jasper report with just a Round Rectangle like this:
[image]

Then I rendered through Java a browser and this it what I get:
[image]

What?
I don't even know what that is, seems like something pulled the circle inside out, twisted it and pulled it back through its own....

Really, any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I found the problem. Under the Rectangle properties, I have set to Radius to 50. This seems to be the problem. I have now set it to 12 and its working perfectly.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`radius` must be less than half of the minimum of the height or width of the rectangle. For example, if the rectangle `height` is 10 and `width` is 20, the maximum of your radius can be up to 5.